# OPENAI key not found, despite positive echo command for the environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, openai-api, api-key

I set the openai key in my bash_profile and when I run echo $OPENAI_API_KEY the key is displayed. However when I want to pass the key in my python project using:

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] or os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") I get the error: openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided.

The key itself is working when I read the key from a file using openai.key_path, but I wanted to switch to accessing the key via environment variable. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance :-)